# How to split traffic in Linux OS using VPN for one purpose only

Tags: vpn

I just want to direct all traffics of certain app for example utorrent with VPN. I already purchased a vpn subscription.
I have found that you can split your traffic using VPN from [here](http://techspree.net/best-vpn-for-torrenting-torrent-vpn/)

But is there any simple way to achieve that using terminal and commands?
I bought IVACY VPN subscription.

Answer (score 0):

You can. I am using UBUNTU and found that in the settings options there you can set the app that will use the VPN. If you can't find the menu then update your vpn client.
I don't know if you will ever need to use console to set this up.